# Syntax error but I don't understand where it's wrong

Tags: javascript, plugins, discord

I've been trying to write a plugin for betterdiscord in JS and everytime I run it it gives me a weird error

```js
module.exports = () => ({
             ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
at Object.compileFuncion (node:vm:360:18)
at Function.U
```

Can anyone help me? Here's the code itself

```js
module.exports = class SpotifyFix {
 start() {
    // Saves the original function
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.realOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;

    // Create new function to filter out URLs
    var myOpen = function(method, url, async, password) {
        //redirects the /pause to /play (cancels it because spotify is already playing)
        if (url == "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/pause") {
            url == "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play"
        
        this.realOpen(method, url, async, password);
    

    // Overwrite original open with modded version
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = myOpen;
        
       }
    }
}

    
stop() {
        XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
            }
        }
```

I already tried asking around and people told me that the export syntax is wrong but the documentation write it that way.

Comment: `Here's the code itself` looks like poor code anyway, e.g. `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;` ??? and the 4th argument to `.open` is `user` not `password` ... sure, that's just a variable name at it can be anything, but it looks wrong.

Comment: If you use module.exports you also need a module bundler, which one are you using? Without a bundler the `module.exports` line won't work.